# Issue with making status bar transparent

Tags: android, statusbar

I know that there are many solutions available for this issue on stackoverflow.
But, In my case I have done below things. Please check once.

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/color_app_theme_medium</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_app_theme_dark</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style>
```

Now, I have mainly two Activities in my overall application.

One of them is simple splash activity and another one is HomeActivity.

Now, Since Home Activity contains **Drawer Layout**, setting property **"fitSystemWindow:true"**
works fine.

and gives me below result.
[image]

Now, I want to achive same thing with my **Splash Activity** which root view is Constrint layout.
I have tried the same thing and fitSystemWindow Property, but the status bar color becomes black.

What might be the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For transparent status bar you can try this code in your main style

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

and if you want to hide status bar in splash screen you can try below line

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```